# How to restart a running webstart application without user intervention?

Tags: java, java-web-start

While a Java Web Start Swing application is running, we would like to cause the application to terminate itself, but be restarted by downloading the updated version from the server. Ideally, the terminated instance should be able to pass a message to the new instance (for example, pass along login data, restore the UI state, ...).

We use Java Web Start, for a GUI application in a client-server context. We have one or two planned maintenance per month, and otherwise, we only do hotfixes. The main difference being that the cluster doesn't go down (as a whole), and the clients can still access the upgraded server, with the non-hotfixed version.

While most users restart their application every morning, and therefore get the updated version, some clients never turn off their PCs, and never actually close the client. This causes them to hit the corrected bugs days after they were fixed.

Our solution would be to force a re-start of the client application between saving their data, and reloading the saved and updated data from the server. The goal being to not cause data loss, but while still forcing the download of the updated version.

Being able to cause the application to restart automatically would make this solution more acceptable for the users.

Comment: This question (so far, without answer), is somewhat related: "download update in background" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088110/java-web-start-download-update-in-background

Comment: Not to sure about the 'auto-restart', but you might look to the [`DownloadService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) to check for updates and the [`PersistenceService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/PersistenceService.html) to store the state of the GUI.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think this will help. This is an old app; we have now well over *1.5M* LOC (client + server, I last checked in 2011). All the data is stored in the cluster, so the server tells the client on every access, if it is outdated, and by how much.

Comment: Maybe a `WindowListener` that checks version and elapsed time on `WINDOW_ACTIVATED`? User would still have to restart manually.